# Add/ Update / delete over large collection in angular application performance issue

Tags: angularjs, json, performance

I have a angular page which shows 1000 of nested record (parent- child up to n-level) and further user can add/edit/delete the record from UI at any location. Each row contains a button to add row above/below, based on that new row is created. This UI has also drag and drop functionality over each row so if any row is draged over another then parent child rows created. For this we have a json collection in nested way and in UI we have created a directive which is called recursively to show the nested record using ng-repeat.

We are facing performance issue here, if user try to add a new row at any specific point we are adding a new blank row in json data on specified index and based on this blank row a blank form is shown which renders very slowly.

Functionality is working but whenever a new add/update/deleted happens over row then it stuck and takes time to re-render the UI.

I cannot implement pagination here to restrict rows as user can create parent child relation by dragging over any row so all record should be shown.

Any one can suggest if other way around for this performance issue?

Comment: You mentioned ng-repeat, are you using angular 1? If so please add the angularjs tag, angular refers to 2.x.x+

Comment: Thanks @BoantaIonut for suggestion

Comment: @RohitKumar is it possible to remove two-way data-binding in at least _some_ places? Even without additional logic, having 1000+ of watchers can make it laggy

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, I can't do it because user can update the content so two way binding needed here.

Comment: `ng-if` destroys DOM (_which can be slow on its own_) and therefore watchers, can you hide some of the data with it?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey,  I already used ng-if but no improvement. Actually in my case loading and showing is working fine, it goes to slow when I do any operation like add/edit/delete.

Comment: you either need to delay the rendering while you are processing addition/editing/deletion (you can always write your own `ng-repeat` directive), or find a way to re-render only nested values (within their level/scope) without affecting the entire json data (maybe you can split it)

Comment: Yes I am still trying to find out other alternative for this. any way thank you so much @AlekseySolovey for your time and suggestion.